# rotating image scale down my image

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, cgaffinetransform

I am working on compass app in ios.I am using the following code to rotate compass

```
        self.compassImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(headingAngle))
```

Its rotating according to my rotation degree.But the image getting scaled to small or big.Please give some idea to solve this.

Comment: set contentmode = AcceptFill may be this will work

Comment: I tried this also..but didnt work:(

Comment: you try AcceptFit as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kept my button on UIView.After that I have rotated my view using the same code.It works fine.